# How do I update the extensionAttributes for a cloud user using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

Microsoft's documentation states

> For an onPremisesSyncEnabled user, the source of authority for this set of properties is the on-premises and is read-only. For a cloud-only user (where onPremisesSyncEnabled is false), these properties may be set during creation or update. These extension attributes are also known as Exchange custom attributes 1-15.

I have confirmed that this user is not sync nor has ever been synced

```
{
    "onPremisesDistinguishedName": null,
    "onPremisesDomainName": null,
    "onPremisesImmutableId": null,
    "onPremisesLastSyncDateTime": null,
    "onPremisesSecurityIdentifier": null,
    "onPremisesSamAccountName": null,
    "onPremisesSyncEnabled": null,
    "onPremisesUserPrincipalName": null,
}
```

Here is my request

```
Server: graph.microsoft.com
Path: /beta/users/<user id removed>
Method: PATCH

Body:
{
    "onPremisesExtensionAttributes": {
        "extensionAttribute14": "8500005",
        "extensionAttribute15": "008500005"
    }
}
```

Response

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Unable to update the specified properties for objects that have originated within an external service.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "...",
            "request-id": "...",
            "client-request-id": "..."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like the old user has some differences with the new user. Based on my test, we can set the extensionAttribute 1-15 for newly created user. But it doesn't work for old users.

Comment: Hi do you still need help on this issue? Does my comment make sense?

Comment: @AllenWu so this looks like a case I need to open with Microsoft then

Comment: You can open a ticket for confirmation.

Comment: Hi do you get a confirmation?

Comment: The response so far is the onPremisesExtensionAttributes cannot be updated for users with an Exchange Online license using the Graph API. They're going to update the documentation as a result of this. I still have the ticket open because I am able to update some users that have an EXO license. I think it's a bug.

Comment: Than you for the reply. It seems that there is not an actual answer for this issue for now. Once you get the issue resolved, would you mind posting an answer for others' reference? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Recently we faced this issue with a client. where old accounts were throwing this error "Unable to update the specified properties for objects that have originated within an external service" when we are trying to use Graph API or Power Automate.

We confirmed with client if they were earlier synced on-premises but IT team had no information of past. So we run the command Set-MsolDirSyncEnabled -EnableDirSync $false

After running this command all extension attributes 1-15 were moved to Exchange online. We raised Microsoft Support ticket to change the source back to Azure AD. But after 1 month of long discussion we were told that "It's NOT Possible to revert back".

We have to create Azure runbook to update these extension attributes using PowerShell

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I do not see how this answers the question at the top of this page, but it should. Please [edit] according to [answer] or delete the answer. Otherwise it risks being flagged as "not an answer" and being deleted.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).